# I've Invented a data encryption method. I wish to know if it's safe

Tags: python-3.x, encryption, random

*I'm not 100% sure if this is the best place to ask this. If so, can you please suggest a better site to me.*

I've written a program in python 3 to encrypt data. But it uses a completely new data encryption method I made. And I wish to know whether any of you think it's secure enough for any practical use. **Or**, if you see any flaws in it.

**The basic gist of the program is this:**

The program converts each character of the data into their ASCII numbers. Then to encrypt it, it "randomly" adds a large number to the original ASCII number of each character.

But it's not random, because the seed has been set using the `random.seed()` function. And The seed the program sets it to is determined by the key.

And then it shuffles each digit.

Due to lack of a better name, I called this method SABONK. It doesn't stand for anything.

```
import random


def ASCII(x): #converts string to ASCII and returns as a list.
    return [ord(c) for c in x]

def ASCII_char(x): #turns a list of ASCII numbers back into text and in a string
    try:
        result = ""
        for i in x:
            result = result + chr(i)
        return result
    except:
        return None

def modifier(key): #returns the "modifier" value used for encryption
    return len(key)*sum(key)

def pad(n, x): #adds 0 to front of number so the length is as required.

    if len(str(x)) >= n: return x
    return ("0"*(n-len(str(x))))+str(x)

class SABONK:
    def __init__(self, key, max=856076, min=100, length=7):
        self.keyString = key
        self.key = ASCII(key)
        self.m = modifier(self.key)

        self.length = 7
        self.maxLength = max
        self.minLength = min

    def setKey(self, newKey):
        pass

    def Encrypt(self, data, password=None): #the main encrypt function
        if data == "": return ""
        #setting up variables needed.
        key = password
        if password == None: key = self.key #If password is None, use the password saved in the class.

        return self.shuffle(self.combine(self.basicEncrypt(data, key)))

    def Decrypt(self, data, password=None, toText=True): #the main encrypt function
        if data == "": return ""
        #setting up variables needed.
        key = password
        if password == None: key = self.key #If password is None, use the password saved in the class.

        if toText: return ASCII_char(self.basicDecrypt(self.disjoin(self.unshuffle(data)), key)) #if toText is True, the function wil return decrypted text and translate it back to characters.
        return self.basicDecrypt(self.disjoin(self.unshuffle(data)), key)#If not, will return list of ASCII numbers


    def basicEncrypt(self, data, password=None): #does the 1/3 part of the encryption process.
        #setting up variables needed.
        key = password
        if password == None: key = self.key #If password is None, use the password saved in the class.

        m = self.m
        if password != self.key: m = modifier(key)
        current = 0 #current refers to the current item in the key list being applied to the encryption process.
        result = []
        data = ASCII(data)

        for x in data:
            random.seed(key[current]*m)#setting the seed
            result.append(pad(self.length, random.randint(self.minLength, self.maxLength)+x))#encrypted character to result

            if current >= (len(key)-1): current = 0 #changing the current item in the key list being applied to the encryption process.
            else: current +=1

            m += x*random.randint(0, 100000) #chaning the modifier

        return result


    def basicDecrypt(self, data, password=None): #does the 1/3 part of the decryption process.
        #setting up variables needed.
        key = password
        if password == None: key = self.key#If password is None, use the password saved in the class.

        m = self.m
        if password != self.key: m = modifier(key)
        current = 0 #current refers to the current item in the key list being applied to the encryption process.
        result = []

        for x in data:
            random.seed(key[current]*m)#setting the seed
            d = x-random.randint(self.minLength, self.maxLength)
            result.append(d)#encrypted character to result

            if current >= (len(key)-1): current = 0 #changing the current item in the key list being applied to the encryption process.
            else: current +=1

            m += d*random.randint(0, 100000) #chaning the modifier

        return result

    def combine(self, data):#combine the numbers from the encrypted data
        result = ""
        for x in data: #going through data list, converting it into string and joining it into single string to retrun
            result = result + str(x)
        return result

    def disjoin(self, data):#disjoin the list of data that was combined by the "combine" function
        l = self.length
        result = []

        while len(data) != 0: #going thorugh the data, converting it into intager and putting it in result list
            result.append(int(data[:l]))
            data = data[l:]
        return result

    def shuffle(self, data, password=None): #data should be a string
        #setting up variables needed.
        key = password
        if password == None: key = self.key#If password is None, use the password saved in the class.

        m = self.m
        if password != self.key: m = modifier(key)
        current = 0 #current refers to the current item in the key list being applied to the random.seed.
        result = []

        l = (len(data) - 1)

        #firist we split the data string into a list, so that every elemnt in the list is a single number
        for x in data:
            result.append(x)


        #And now we shuffle the list
        for x in range(6*len(data)):
            random.seed(key[current]*m)#setting the seed

            i1 = random.randint(0, l) #choosing the two indexes of the data list to swap
            i2 = i1
            while i2 == i1: i2 = random.randint(0, l) #this makes sure i2 is different from i1
            result[i1], result[i2] = result[i2], result[i1]

            current +=1
            if current >= (len(key)-1): current = 0 #changing the current item in the key list being applied to the encryption process.
            m += 1

        return "".join(result)

    def unshuffle(self, data, password=None): #data should be a string
        #setting up variables needed.
        key = password
        if password == None: key = self.key#If password is None, use the password saved in the class.
        m = self.m
        if password != self.key: m = modifier(key)
        current = 0 #current refers to the current item in the key list being applied to the random.seed.
        result = []
        actionsList = []
        l = (len(data) - 1)

        #firist we split the data string into a list, so that every elemnt in the list is a single number
        for x in data:
            result.append(x)

        #figure out list of swaps the shuffle dunctionn would have taken.
        for x in range(6*len(str(data))): 
            random.seed(key[current]*m)#setting the seed

            i1 = random.randint(0, l) #choosing the two indexes of the data list to swap
            i2 = i1
            while i2 == i1: i2 = random.randint(0, l) #this makes sure i2 is different from i1

            actionsList.append([i1,i2])
            current +=1
            if current >= (len(key)-1): current = 0 #changing the current item in the key list being applied to the encryption process.
            m += 1

        actionsList = list(reversed(actionsList))#Then reverse the list, so the swaps can be undone.


        #And now we unshuffle the list
        for x in range(6*len(str(data))):
            result[actionsList[x][0]], result[actionsList[x][1]] = result[actionsList[x][1]], result[actionsList[x][0]]

        return "".join(result)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    key = input("Please type out key: ")
    s = SABONK(key)
    text = input("Please type out text to encrypt: ")
    print("You have typed: " + text)
    e = s.Encrypt(text)
    print("Text Encrypted: "+ e)
    print("Text Decrypted: "+ str(s.Decrypt(e)))
```

Comment: There are many existing, tested and secure algorithms for this, that have had thousands and thousands of eyes examining that code. Why would you reinvent the wheel on your own and take the risk that it's safe rather than just use one of them?

Comment: This program I've written was a product of not really understanding the stuff I was finding on the internet about data encryption, and just deciding to make my own algorithm.

Comment: And now I'd like to know how it compares to real world data encryption algorithm.

Comment: I never said I can't. Just that I wasn't. If I wanted to I could sit down and find some proper materials to read. But I didn't. I started getting the idea for this method instead, and I decided to create it and see how it pans out. This is a hobby project, not work. So it's not a vital for me to understand the workings of standard encryption programs. And now I just want to know how it compares to the standard encryption methods.

Comment: I thought I addressed how it compares in my first comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I wish to know whether any of you think it's secure enough for any practical use.

In a word, no. It takes many years of studying mathematics and cryptography to remotely understand how modern ciphers are designed, and the incredibly subtle flaws that mathematicians have discovered over years of research.

Stanford's online [Cryptography I](https://online.stanford.edu/courses/soe-y0001-cryptography-i) course is a good introduction to some of the concepts, but you will need at least university-level math skills. The [Cryptopals Crypto Challenges](https://cryptopals.com/sets/1) can also teach you something about modern cryptography, but beware, these challenges get incredibly difficult.

While coming up with ciphers recreationally can be fun, please don't use your ciphers to protect anything actually sensitive, and do not misrepresent the security of your cipher to others.

Sites like [r/codes](https://reddit.com/r/codes) are places where you can post "hobby ciphers" like this. And the book "The Code Book" by Simon Singh is a good read regarding different historic ciphers and how they were broken.

---

Have you considered things like:

- `basicEncrypt` generates numbers that are at most 6 digits, then pads them to 7 digits. This may cause issues such as making your shuffle algorithm heavily biased towards shuffling padding digits.
- The length of `data` affects the probability that a given digit will be swapped or not.
- If you use the same key twice on data of the same size, it will generate the same shuffling pattern.
- You heavily rely on `random.seed()`, do you know what it is actually doing under the hood? Is it safe to use for secure purposes?

Comment: Another useful reference is Bruce Schneier's [Memo to the Amateur Cipher Designer](https://www.schneier.com/crypto-gram/archives/1998/1015.html#cipherdesign).